# I can't create a bootable win 10 pen drive

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10

I used to have win 10 installed until that last update 20H2 after it's done windows was down; black screen with cursor, then i tried so many things from the internet nothing worked, so i completely formatted my hard drive from the bios and tried to create a bootable pen drive with android phone by Etchdroid it wasn't bootable then i tried ubuntu and it worked after i tried many other windows versions, and here i am, I've been trying create a bootable windows pin drive for 3 days while learning Linux and now it's the end of the third day and i'm hopeless,

1. rufus and unetbootin doesn't recognize any flash drive and woeusb
   can't be installed
2. tried to use an app like poweriso to just copy the iso content to the ntfs formatted pindrive still unbootable only ubuntu was bootable.
3. tried that here https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/09/uefi-ntfs-bootable-windows-usb-linux.html

everytime i choose the USB drive from boot menu even though its the first in the menu it just boots into ubuntu and if i left it to open automatically it opens ubuntu

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: There are two methods at this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/1310311#1310311 that have worked well for me. If your system is UEFI then Ventoy should also work. These methods should work with any supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @David: Why do you say this question should include the version of Ubuntu. It is not required. Don't make up new rules, Ask Ubuntu has enough as is.

Comment: @David Please deliberate about your requests for information, and tailor each of your comments to the specific question. In an unmet dependencies question the requested information may be essential, because without it the question would be unclear. In a different question different information may be needed to prevent the question from being closed as unclear.

Comment: @David I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, first question u gotta excuse me. 
thank you guys, I gave the link in point nom.3 another try. from the boot menu 
 I shouldn't have chosen the name of the USB to boot from, there was another option called USB hard drive idk how it worked.

Answer (score 2):

To create a windows bootable USB, use `mkusb`, to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mkusb usb-pack-efi
```

[help.ubuntu/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: Mkusb-dus works well creating a Windows installer however mkusb-plug has some extra safeguards to insure everything goes in the right place. +10